# Variable substitution to get the file name and extension in bash

Tags: bash, variables, substitution

I found the following "trick" to get the file name and its extension.

```
filename="my file.ext"
name=${filename%.*}
ext=${filename#*.}
```

Could you explain those `${filename%.*}` and `${filename#*.}` things and give a link to the relevant documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
${filename%.*}   
# % Deletes shortest match of pattern ".*" from back of "filename".

${filename#*.}   
# Deletes the pattern '*.' from front of filename i.e. removes the name
```

The Linux Documentation project has this page on [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). Go down to the section marked substring removal

Comment: I recommend saying "pattern" instead of "regex". These aren't regexes.

Comment: Agreed, hadn't quite finished editing it when you posted. :-)

Comment: Also: `%%` and `##` will remove the maximum possible, rather than the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

These are both a form of "Remove matching prefix pattern" see [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and search for `Remove matching prefix pattern`.